# How to remove the large file commit in history from the repo genrated by git svn clone operation?

Tags: github, svn, git-svn, git-lfs

I created a repo "test-repo" on Github enterprise site and run following commands to push the local repo (c:\mytempdir) generated by git svn clone operation.

```
cd c:\mytempdir
git remote add origin https://PAT@github.azc.ext.xx.com/liang-ming/test-repo
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

It failed with the error about some sdf files are larger than 100M.

```
remote: error: Please visit https://www.yammer.com/xx.com/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=6603278
remote: error: File HH.sdf is 104.75 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File HHx.sdf is 113.50 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File HH/xxx.sdf is 117.44 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.azc.ext.xx.com/liang-ming/test-repo
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://PAT@github.azc.ext.xx.com/liang-ming/test-repo'
```

I searched the sdf files in c:\mytempdir, did not find any sdf file larger than 100M, so I guess it was the large file in the SVN commit history.

So I tried the BFG, it said it did not find any file larger than 100M.
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

```
java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M C:\mytempdir
```

I also tried to use LFS to track "*.sdf" files as mentioned in the following link, but it did not resolve the error.

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial

Any solution to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is the svn history important to preserve? If not really, you could squash all history into a single commit and push that; this way it's guaranteed that historic revisions of large blobs will be absent. That's one option. It's hard to say if/how BFG malfunctioned without you sharing the repo.